# Equivalence classes on a relationship in $R$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

There is a relationship on $\Bbb R$ defined aRb if a-b is a rational number.  I already proved its an equivalence relation in $\Bbb R$. My question is how to describe the equivalence classes?  Here is my attempt at the answer:

[0]=$\{x\in \Bbb R : xR0\}$ = $\{x\in \Bbb R : x-0 $ is rational $\}$

[a]=$\{x\in \Bbb R : xRa\}$ = $\{x\in \Bbb R : x-a $ is rational$\}$

Comment: +1 for showing your thoughts.  Seems reasonable to me, but how do we know there aren't separate classes $\frac 12$ and $\frac 14$?

Comment: One thing to get you started is that any rational number $[q]$ represents all $\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: @ShankaraPailoor:  Looks like drew gets that.  I don't know how to present that, which seems to be the question.

Comment: Let $t$ be irrational. If $x-t$ is rational, then $x-t = \frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and so $b(x-t) = a$. So $x-t$ must actually be an integer, yes? What does it mean when two decimals have integer difference?

Comment: @KirkBoyer Lets see if I understand this now.  The reals can be partioned into the rationals and irrationals.  Where in this case the rationals are [0].  The irrationals are [a] becasue like you said for $b(x-t)=a$ x-t must have the same decimals.  To anser Ross Millikan why there are not seperate classes is because if $\frac12 R 0 $ and $\frac14 R 0 $ then by symmetry and transitivity $\frac12 R \frac14 $

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$[x] = \{x + q : q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Thus $[0] = \{0 + q : q \in \mathbb{Q}\} = \{q : q \in \mathbb{Q}\} = \mathbb{Q}$.

To see this, note that by your definition, $[x]$ is the set of all $a$ such that $a - x = q$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $a = x + q$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

---

If you know some group theory, an alternatively (but essentially equivalent) way of thinking of the equivalent using coset. $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is an abelian group. $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is a normal subgroup. Hence the equivalence classes are the elements of the group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$.